# Time drifting like crazy on Windows Server

Tags: windows-server-2012, time

Time on my home server gets behind very quickly, and in one day it can get hours off. I already replaced the CMOS battery but it does not have any effect. Anyway the battery should not matter if it's powered on I suppose. Internet time NTP sync does not work because the difference gets too big too quickly. Interesting thing is that eventlog system is spammed a lot around every minute by messages from kernel-general eventid 1 like:

> The system time has changed to ‎2020‎-‎07‎-‎11T18:11:00.000000000Z from ‎2020‎-‎07‎-‎11T18:11:00.240125700Z.
> Change Reason: An application or system component changed the time.
>
> or
>
> from ‎2020‎-‎07‎-‎10T19:30:13.500468400Z. Change Reason: System time
> synchronized with the hardware clock.The system time has changed to ‎2020‎-‎07‎-‎10T18:30:13.500000000Z

I have made myself a little script which gets the time from NTP and sets it even if it is very different, but I don't like this workaround.

But the biggest mystery is, that I have already replaced motherboard and CPU and still it's the same, so it might be something in software? It is Windows Server 2012.

EDIT:
an example how time suddenly jumps one hour behind!
[image]

Comment: "An application or system component changed the time." Hunt down the app doing this, might not be easy.

Comment: well the first one just went forward 0.240 secs so it might be NTP, I am concenred about the change with HW - can you check the time in BIOS? is this a physical or virtual server?

Comment: I wrote that it's my little home server and I replaced CPU and motherboard, so it is a physical machine obviously ;-)

Comment: sorry was late when reading :) - so what about the BIOS HW time?

Comment: not sure what you mean BIOS HW time. I managed to finally connect an external monitor, keyboard and mouse, switched off the machine and after powerup looked into BIOS. The time was ten minutes behind! So I have set it properly and it was fine in windows. Before I managed to move monitor back to my primary PC and logged via RDP the time was already 2 minutes behind! Strangely enough it seems like it does not get worse. It stays 2 minutes behind for last 20 minutes...

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. one is the HW time one is the OS time. Just found [this explanation where Windows expects local time in HW clock - while *nix systems shoudl be set to UTC](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/84dd824b-dd35-4d71-8d92-dbc29c78a2a4/hardware-clock-in-utc?forum=w8itproinstall) so you should check against what your server is set to sync its time and check if your primary computer has the same settings - which should ensure the same time on both.

Comment: the computer hardware clock in BIOS is in UTC, so it shows 2 hours less then in OS for my timezone, but that's not the issue. It's the mysterious delaying. Did you see the screenshot I added to question?

Comment: yes, I saw the screenshot. that is why I send you the link - which says that windows expects local time in HW clock (BIOS). and your screenshot looks kind of ok, event is logged at 15:30 and it says the system changed from 14:30 to 13:30 - which you described is your time. what happens if you set the BIOS clock to your real time?

Comment: Have you found the cause? My recently built desktop is having this issue... time is drifting.. it is driving me nuts..